# Google API returns 400 BadRequest for batch request

Tags: node.js, google-api, gmail

I'm trying to send bath request to [GMail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/batch) using [request](https://github.com/request/request#custom-http-headers) for nodejs. The problem is even trough I generate the same query as in documentation, gmail always respond with **400 BadRequest**

Those are my headers in form of json

```
{ 'Content-Type': 'multipart/mixed; boundary=c2db2692-8877-4159-bf02-03e6c5d3ffbf',
  authorization: 'Bearer MY_TOKEN',
  'content-length': 231 }
```

Example of body content

```
--c2db2692-8877-4159-bf02-03e6c5d3ffbf
Content-Type: application/http
Content-ID: <item1:12930812@barnyard.example.com>


GET /gmail/v1/users/sneg0k32@gmail.com/messages/14c6c0c43e9bb16b


--c2db2692-8877-4159-bf02-03e6c5d3ffbf--
```

Any suggestions why this happens? **Request** generates extra few spaces and make headers in lowercase, however I'm not sure if this is the problem.

Example of nodejs code

```
request({
    method: 'POST',
    uri: 'https://www.googleapis.com/batch',
    auth: {
      bearer: key
    },
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/mixed'
    },
    multipart: _.map(queries, function(query) {
      return {
        'Content-Type': 'application/http',
        'Content-ID': "<item1:12930812@barnyard.example.com>",
        body: 'GET ' + query
      }
    })
  }, function(error, response, body) {

    console.log(response.request.headers)
    _.map(response.request.body, function(chunk) {
      console.log(chunk.toString())
    })

    console.log(body)

  })
```

**UPD:** This is clearly an issue with how I make my node call, send same request via HTTPTester and everything worked fine

**UPD2**: Decided to use bachelor, however I haven't figured what was causing this issue with plain request

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite hard to troubleshoot such a problem. I would more than likely say it's down to the spaces. I had a similar issue that was because the request body was seen as invalid due to it's structure.

Uppercase or lowercase headers shouldn't cause an issue.

If it helps I've created a node module to creating batch requests: https://www.npmjs.com/package/batchelor. Feel free to use it.

Comment: I had an issue with batchelor, it expects response content-type to have boundary field, which not always present (batchelor.js:170). I  will create issue now

Comment: Actually there is no issues with library itself, just mistake in documentation